# A linux tftpd server that can log the incoming requests to stdout/stderr

Tags: logging

I find it crazy that this doesn't work out of the box, but neither atftpd nor tftpd-hpa seem to have any way to log to the console. I've run them in the foreground with verbosity right up but clearly that's not the right magic incantation.

I'm running a short-lived server for a firmware upload and I want to see the requests (and ideally when they've completed).

Answer (score 0):

After some more experimentation, here's what James was aiming for back in 2010, in a form tested to work on Kubuntu Linux 20.04 LTS:

```
sudo atftpd --logfile - --no-fork --verbose=5 --trace --daemon /srv/tftp
```

The key details are as follows:

- `--logfile /dev/stdout` apparently doesn't work in the X11 terminal emulators I was trying, but `--logfile -` does. What's misleading is that it *appears* to work, in that *some* output is produced.
- `--verbose 3` doesn't produce any request logging. You need at least `--verbose 5` for that. (`--verbose 7 --trace` is maximum verbosity)
- `/srv/tftp` is the default TFTP root path on *buntu that will be set up when you install `atftpd`.

Here's the result:

```
ssokolow@monolith ~ % sudo atftpd --logfile - --no-fork --verbose=5 --daemon /srv/tftp
Jan 16 18:33:28 monolith atftpd[2933437.140296925675584]: Advanced Trivial FTP server started (0.7)
Jan 16 18:33:32 monolith atftpd[2933437.140296925587200]: Serving default to 192.168.0.2:41416
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

`atftpd --logfile /dev/stdout --no-fork --verbose 3 --daemon /tftpboot`